# How to stream Webcam in WPF?

Tags: wpf, streaming, webcam, mediaelement

Can I stream a live video in WPF application from my web cam? If yes, then How?

Comment: it is possible, I did this for my entry for the codemaster competition a few years ago.  See in action here - http://video.google.ca/videoplay?docid=-2891564165965980591&ei=Xw1iSdn-NIyG-wHX94yrCA&q=dradis+codemaster&hl=en

I'll dig up the code and post more when I get home from work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to use DirectX Capture or something (is not in WPF right know, so use DirectX API's directly).

Look at: [WPF Media Kit](http://www.codeplex.com/WPFMediaKit). It can grab the Vista Windows desktop manager DirectX Direct3D shared Surface, and use it as a visual brush in WPF. He does some nice things with it. Look at his [blog](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/278/Vista-DWM-Hacking-Capture-and-Stream-D3D-WPF-Windows-Real-Time.aspx) where he explains it.

I hope this helps you on your way...

UPDATE 2009-11-06:
The [VideoRenderElement](http://videorendererelement.codeplex.com) Codeplex project has an example on how to stream webcam content.
[This project](http://videorendererelement.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screen%20Shots&referringTitle=Home) looks like it would fit your requirment perfectly.

UPDATE 2013-02-18:
Alternatively one can use the [Expression Encoder SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602440%28v=expression.40%29.aspx). For an example you can look at the [WPF-Webcam-Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control) article on CodeProject

Comment: Are we still have to use WPF Media Kit no days or there is something else? Any updates? Thank you!

Comment: @Peretz: actually today I saw this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control He uses the Expression Encoder SDK. I've updated my answer based on this.

Comment: Yeah... I know this article. I have used it. The main problem that streaming presets are limited for FREE version. :( We have to pay 200 dollars to use ALL possible streaming presets.