# My x64 WPF app needs x32 DLLs for Microsoft.Lifecam.*.dll integration. Any ideas for allowing both?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to integrate my Microsoft LifeCam Studio into a 64bit C# application but I can't find 64 bit dlls.

**1.**  Does anyone know where I can find 64 bit versions of:

> Microsoft.LifeCam.Camera.dll 
>   Microsoft.LifeCam.Framework.dll
>   Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer.dll

**2.**  Is there a way to import and use the above 32 bit DLLs in a 64 bit WPF app?  When I try to reference and use them, I get the following compile warnings and then related runtime errors.

> *Warning  1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "Microsoft.LifeCam.Camera, Version=4.25.512.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime
>   failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture
>   of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the
>   processor architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.*

I wrote the following application to demonstrate my issue.   This compiles and runs great in 32 bit mode.  As soon as I switch the compiler to target x64, I get expected errors.

1. New WPF Application
2. Add References:

   > Microsoft.LifeCam.Camera.dll 
   >   Microsoft.LifeCam.Framework.dll
   >   Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer.dll
3. MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.LifeCam;

namespace LifecamTest32Bit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CameraList cameras = new CameraList();
                if (cameras.Count < 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No imaging device found.", "No Camera", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                    return;
                }
                Camera cam = (Camera)cameras[0];
                Streamer streamer = new Streamer(cam, previewControl, false);
                streamer.CurrentVideoResolutionIndex = 1; //selecting a resolution.
                streamer.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<!-- language-all: lang-xaml -->
<Window x:Class='LifecamTest32Bit.MainWindow'    
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"            
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  xmlns:strm="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LifeCam;assembly=Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
  Loaded="Window_Loaded">
  <Grid>
    <strm:PreviewView Name="previewControl" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft never released an SDK for LifeCam, those DLLs are not APIs. They are part of the software, and it is very unlikely you will get Microsoft to write a 64 bit version for the software.

What you want to do with undocumented DLls anyway? Microsoft has no code contract with you to keep the interface working. In fact Microsoft could push an update to the software next Tuesday to remove the dll altogether.

If you want to work with webcams, work with official APIs like DirectShow or Media Foundation. See [How to stream Webcam in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412995/how-to-stream-webcam-in-wpf) and [Video preview in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209255/video-preview-in-c-sharp) for suggestions.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm currently using the AVICap window class but I'm not satisfied with the way it looks.  I decided to use the LifeCam DLLs as another quick and dirty approach for better preview quality.  I'll take a look at the links and see if I can find more about changing quality settings.

Comment: AVICap (VFW) was deprecated in the 1990s, most webcams work with DirectShow.

Comment: I'm confused.  Wasn't DirectShow deprecated? It appears that Windows Media Foundation was the suggested solution from Vista on and it is still suggested today.  Is that correct?  Where does the Expression Encoder SDK come in then?

Comment: MF is for vista+. If you have the luxury to drop XP support then go ahead use MF. Encoder SDK has a control to display preview, however the Expression line is discontinued and I don't suggest you to invest time in it.